# Pre-built NPM package: How can I spare users my dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I inherited maintenance of an NPM package. It is a little unusual in that its `main` file is in `dist/`; it’s built with webpack (via `npm run build`).

This is fine for our purposes, but when we install this package into a consuming application, we get just oodles and oodles of dependencies. It’s adding *minutes* to the consumer’s `npm install` time, and all for nothing, as the `main` is already built.

I’m pretty sure we’re “doing it wrong.” Is there a better way to distribute an `npm` package that delivers a pre-built `js` file such that dependencies aren’t needlessly passed on to users?

Comment: What is the purpose of the dependencies if everything that is needed is in the bundled/built javascript file? Are they dependencies used to create the bundle/build? If that is the case, it seems like you could make them `devDependencies` instead.

Comment: Create gulp/grunt/npm script task to build all your sources into `dist` folder for example, and copy into it `package.json` (readme and other related files). After that run `npm publish` not from **the root folder** but from `dist` folder.

Comment: @mscdex Yes, they are needed to create the build (and run the test suite). They are indeed `devDependencies`, but `npm install` does still install such dependencies, at least in non-production mode.

Comment: @AlexanderMac Yeah, maybe that’s the ticket. Publishing from dist. Presumably that would be a separate package…

Comment: End users that `npm install my-module` don't get `devDependencies` installed, only if they do `npm install` inside the module's root directory. Or is this a package that is distributed in some way other than `npm install my-module` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mscdex nailed it. I wasn’t aware that `npm` already behaves the way I wanted: `npm install` *will* install `devDependencies` by default, but *only your direct, top-level `devDependencies`, not recursively.* So your dependencies' `devDepedencies` will *not* be installed.

Good to know.